# Update manager updated without prompting for a password

Tags: sudo, xubuntu

As far as I'm aware, I'm supposed to be prompted for a password before anything installs, but just now, I told update manager to install updates, and it proceeded to installing them without prompting me for a password. This happened right after I logged on, so I wasn't prompted for my password beforehand for anything else either.

Is this normal and would it pose any kind of security risk?

Comment: Look at your `/etc/sudoers` file (you'll need root permission to see it).  Is there a line that's not commented out and says `NOPASSWD`?

Comment: @Kevin: "NOPASSWD" doesn't exist anywhere in the file. I have a line that starts with "Default" and three others, with varying number of "ALL"s and punctuation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should look into [PolicyKit](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PolicyKit), as some update manager backend (such as the popular PackageKit) use it to authorize themselves.

Comment: It seems this could be it. Where would I look to see what PolicyKit authorized?

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite familiar with it too, just know a little that it "works" :-(