# How to disable password prompting for automatic updates on Red Hat

Tags: rhel, package-management, non-root-user

Basically, I have the opposite problem of [this guy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30136/update-manager-updated-without-prompting-for-a-password). I would like my updates to be installed in a transparent way : I'm tired of entering my password every time.

I'm running on Red Hat (6.2 to be precise).

I saw a script somewhere saying that you need to edit a line containing "admin" in visudo, but I don't have that line. It was meant for Ubuntu, maybe that's the reason why...

Comment: The answer is the same though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the solution is to modify the local PolicyKit definitions.  Create a file called, say, /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/allowuserupdate.pkla

```
[Allow User Updates]
Identity=*
Action=org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-update
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes
```

If you only want your user, you could change `Identity=YOURUSERNAME` (replace `YOURUSERID` with your username).

Answer (score 0):

Allow user **bob** and group **update-users** to run yum without password.

```
bob, %update-users ALL= NOPASSWD: /sbin/yum
```

Only allow bob such access

```
bob, %update-users ALL= NOPASSWD: /sbin/yum
```

*Note:* I don't have a RedHat box to verify the location of yum.  Please tell me if this location is invalid.

Comment: PackageKit, not yum.

Comment: I'm confused where the user stated he or she is using PackageKit vs yum.  Last time I used RH (10 years ago), they were using yum.  If PackageKit is being used, then the user should simply replace PackageKit binary with suggested yum binary in the above.

Comment: No, because PackageKit uses PolicyKit.

Comment: Personnaly, I'm not using anything. I'm ready to use whatever will do the job.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `yum -y update`?

Comment: Why would you run `yum` when using PackageKit?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams because it is the way the service yum-cron used to do it.